# SQL Server : How to run one query on multiple databases(same schema) which is on different instances

Tags: sql-server

There are same databases on different SQL Server 2008 instances, but data is unique. I need to run the same query on every database. Is it possible to run the same query on all the instances at same time?

Comment: Maybe you can use them as linked servers

Comment: If by same time you mean to run one query against all of your databases in all the different servers I also think linked servers is a posible solution.

Comment: I know to link the server,but don't know how to run the query after that.query is like this " select column1,column2 from same table name and same db name but  on different instance name.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM [Linked_Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table]`

Comment: but i wanted the outcome as combined/merged.

Answer (score 1):

You can add your servers as linked servers to one of the instances and run the query which will be of the following form:

```
SELECT * FROM [Linked_Server1].[Database].[Schema].[Table] AS S1
UNION
SELECT * FROM [Linked_Server1].[Database].[Schema].[Table] AS S2
UNION
SELECT * FROM [Linked_Server3].[Database].[Schema].[Table] AS S3
....
```

Generally for statements you can simply refer to a table of a specific Server with the four part identifier `[Server].[Database].[Schema].[Table]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `OPENDATASOURCE` function:

**OPENDATASOURCE (Transact-SQL):**
Provides ad hoc connection information as part of a four-part object name without using a linked server name.

```
OPENDATASOURCE ( provider_name, init_string )
```

- `provider_name`

  > Is the name registered as the *PROGID* of the *OLE DB provider* used to access the data source. `provider_name` is a **char** data type, with no default value.
- `init_string`

  > Is the connection string passed to the **IDataInitialize** interface of the destination provider. The provider string syntax is based on keyword-value pairs separated by semicolons, such as: `'keyword1=value; keyword2=value'`.

The following example creates an *ad hoc connection* to the `Payroll` instance of SQL Server on server `London`, and queries the `AdventureWorks2008R2.HumanResources.Employee` table. (Use `SQLNCLI` and `SQL Server` will redirect to the latest version of SQL Server Native Client OLE DB Provider.)

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENDATASOURCE('SQLNCLI',
    'Data Source=London\Payroll;Integrated Security=SSPI')
    .AdventureWorks2008R2.HumanResources.Employee
```